# Improve VBA Array Read Performance

Tags: arrays, vba, performance

A 145 million array reads is taking 6 seconds.  How can it be made faster?

```
Dim X As Integer

X = 0
For Y = 1 To 17000
    For Yn = Y To 17000
        d = Ary(Yn, X)
    Next
Next
```

Ary(Yn, X) is variant/date.
Ary size is ~ 17000 x 7

The loop without the array reads is 1.5 seconds.  The array reads adds 6.5 seconds.

Comment: Doing *anything* 145 Million times takes time, even for a computer. The only way to make it faster is to find a way not to read it so many times.

Comment: Reading the *same* value up to 17,000 times indicates that you're not using the right data structure.

Comment: @NOYB The way the question is posed, this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please provide more details around what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ThunderFrame
Maybe it's an X-Y problem for you.  But not for me.  I asked exactly what I want to know about.  Which is if d = Ary(Yn, X) can be made faster.  The loop is a means by which to do it a lot of times.

Comment: The point is that your code makes no sense to the people reading this and want to help you, so take a hint and [edit] your post. Your code overwrites the same value over and over and over - that loop is useless. You give us an assignment to an array index read, which is O(1) complexity, the fetch is exactly the same operarion whether it's 2, or 2 million iterations you make. Your princess is in another castle.

Comment: @Mat's Mug
No.  The loop is not useless.  And it overwrites the same variable but with different value from ary(Yn, X).  The assignment is not about the value nor the loop efficiency.  It is about the d = Ary(Yn, X) efficiency.
You are asking for information that is not relevant to the assignment.

Comment: @Mat's Mug
ThunderFrame presented a good idea re: not using variant array.  But that will create some complexities in other parts.  So probably not going to go there.  Perfectly willing to accept that d = Ary(Yn, X) performance cannot be suitably improved.  As braX already pointed out in my accepted answer.  In which case if I chose to pursue other means of performance improvement I may ask different questions.  But those are not this question.

Comment: And just how did you manage to conclude that the bottleneck must be the code you're deeming "relevant"? The accepted answer is suggesting to switch languages, because CPU cycles are magically faster when it's not VBA code that's involved. If you want any meaningful improvement on your code, post it **all** on [codereview.se]. Here on this site this type of question is too broad, see [ask].

Comment: @Mat's Mug
Because the question is about performance of d = Ary(Yn, X).  The loop is only there to make it happen a lot of times to illustrate the performance.
Yes I know the loop is not efficient.  And yes I know ways to make the loop more efficient.  But loop efficiency is not the objective of the question.  Forget about the loop and any other code.  Only concerned with possibilities of making d = Ary(Yn, X) more efficient.  Both braX and ThunderFrame picked up on that right away.  Why can't you?

Comment: In other words you're wasting everyone's time. Cheers.

Comment: You should be aware that these types of questions can *super* annoying to programmer/coding-types, who are by nature curious people who like to fix things, and like to ask questions about things they've been asked to help with.  Your "you don't need to know that" responses to perfectly reasonable requests can be read as arrogant/dismissive and don't exactly encourage anyone to assist.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is incomplete or meaningless. you read the value of an array 144,508,500 million times, but you discard the result 144,508,499 times.

If you only care about the last result, I'll optimize that for you:

```
Dim X As Integer
d = Ary(17000, X)
```

Tell us what you really want to do, and we provide a better answer.

There are a few general things you can do:

Don't use a Variant/Date array - Variants use more memory, and if they're read from Excel, there's some overhead in preserving the date format of the region. You'd be better off with a Date array, and I suspect, even better off with an array of Doubles.

Assuming you're intending on doing some kind of date comparison, you're re-reading multiple rows, multiple times. Look into using the Dictionary object, and you can likely reduce the number of reads dramatically.

Comment: The code is the relevant part of the loop.  There is other processing that uses d.  This question is only regarding performance of the acquisition of d from the array.

The Array is 2 dimensional of type variant and is populated with dates and values (real numbers).  How would I go about using type date for column 0 and double for columns 1 through 6?  Is that possible to have a multi-type array?
Nowhere did I mention Excel.  This is strictly VBA.
Avoiding tying to objects.